# How to get keyevent in java without textfield or textarea?

Tags: java, keyevent

I am studying about GUI in java. Now, i am coding a tiny program about button, and i have a question. In common, i use mouse to click a button and i set a Message Dialog appear but now, I want to set a method. In this method, i use `KeyEvent`, i want to press a key and the program will automatically choice the button without mouse. I have used TextArea and `TextField` and now i want to use this method without `TextArea` and `TextField`.
Example: when i click the button, the message dialog appear, now instead of click the button, when i press <kbd>A</kbd>, the message dialog will appear.
Please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For larger event-handling I suggest @Chris' suggestion but for something as small as yours - i.e., calling a simple method upon keyPress, I'd personally go with an anonymous listener

```
.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {  
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {  
        //method call goes here 
    }  
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain for me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `KeyListener` to your `JFrame`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) is an excellent tutorial.

**Example**

Let's create a class that implements our `KeyListener`, and let's assume you've got a class that extends `JFrame`, called `Program`.

```
public class KeyMapper implements KeyListener
{
    // Lots of methods will need to be written. I won't do them all.

    private Program world;

    public KeyMapper(Program world)
    {
         this.world = world;  
    }

    /**
     * This is the event that fires when a key is hit.
     * @param e the event object passed when a key is hit.
     * @Override
     */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyChar() == 't') {
             world.callMethod(); 
         }
    }
}
```

`KeyMapper` will now call a method in your program, whenever `t` is hit. To add this to your `Program`, you can use the following line:

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyMapper(this));
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand :( here is the applet viewer of my program. It's emulater of the MineSweeper game: 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/99589920@N03/11222868664/
My idea is using keyboard instead of mouse click to choose the button.
Can you give me your facebook or your email? Please, i really need it !